# How should my SideBar know which <router-outlet> is active

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a `LayoutComponent` which has `HeaderComponent` with `[routerLink]` for each separate page

**header.componenet.html**

```html
     <a [routerLink]="['services/individuals/info1']">
        Info 1
     </a>
     <a [routerLink]="['services/individuals/info2']">
        Info 2 
     </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['services/legals/info3']">
        Info 3
     </a>
     <a [routerLink]="['services/legals/info4']">
        Info 4
     </a>
....
```

The reason why I have such route `services/` `individuals` or `legal` is that depending on `individuals` or `legal` I show content with different type sidebars . For `individuals` background is yellow `legal` is brown and depending on which link is active (f.e: /individuals/info1 or /legals/info3) I want to make sub-item in sidebar be active.

**service-sidebar.component.html**

```html
    <aside class="services-page__nav">
            <div>
                SIDEBAR
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-item active"> // switch active if route is on Info 2
                <div class="services-page__nav-item active">
                   Info 1 // if legal route is active then Info 3
                </div>
                <a href="sidebar-item">
                    Info 2 // if legal route is active then Info 4
                </a>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Here is my , `ServiceComponent` which is layout for `individuals` and `legal` menu

**service.component.html**

```html
    <section>
        <div class="container">
                <app-service-sidebar></app-service-sidebar> // here I need to pass data or smth to know which route is active
                <router-outlet></router-outlet> // here content changes depending on chosen route
        </div>
    
    </section>
```

Here how I defined my routes

**routes.ts**

```typescript
    const main_menu = [
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: MainPageComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'contacts',
            component: ContactsComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'services',
            component: ServicesComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: '**',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                },
                {
                    path: 'individuals',
                    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/services/individuals/individuals.module').then(m => m.IndividualsModule)
                },
                {
                    path: 'legals',
                    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/services/legals/legals.module').then(m => m.LegalsModule)
                }
    
            ],
        }
    
    ];
```

PLease help . Or may be I have chosen wrong strategy for routing model ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **routerLinkActive** in **anchor** tag with your desired css class name

Comment: how routerLinkActive  would know if url leagl or individual is f.e services/legals/info3 and services/individuals/info1

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive this document will help you